# Не меняется тип колонки в DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Пытаюсь поменять тип колонки из числового на строчный но не получается. В чем может быть проблема ?

Данные вытаскиваются из БД Mysql, тип поля "type" smallint(1)

kontr_dg -  DataGridView

```
kontr_dg.Columns["type"].ValueType = typeof(string);


string _typeID = kontr_dg.Rows[i].Cells["type"].Value.ToString();
string _type = core.kontr_type(_typeID);
kontr_dg.Rows[i].Cells["type"].Value = _type.ToString();

//Перевод числа в строку
public string kontr_type(string type)
{
   string _type;
   if (type == "1") _type = "Заказчик";
   else _type = "Перевозчик";
   return _type;
}
```

на выходе выходит ошибка [image: Не меняется тип колонки в DataGridView]

Comment: Как Вы создаете свой kontr_dg? Откуда потребность в kontr_dg.Columns["type"].ValueType = typeof(string); ? Уберите все лишнее и посмотрите в отладчике как отрабатывается kontr_dg.Rows[i].Cells["type"].Value = "Test";

Answer (score 1):

datagrid заполняется из бд. Потребность нужна была для того чтобы вместо значения 1, было значение "Заказчик". Проблема была решена путем изменения типа поле в бд из smallint в varchar.